Lemma about $n$-adic numbers
In the book I am reading there is the following Lemma whose prove is "left for the reader":
Lemma:
For $n \in \mathbb{N},n\geq 2$ we define the ring of $n$-adic numbers
$\mathbb{Z}_n=\{(\overline{x_k}) \in \prod_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/n^{k+1}\mathbb{Z} : x_{k+1} \equiv x_k \mod n^{k+1}\}$.
Then,

For coprime $n,m \geq 2, \mathbb{Z}_{nm} \cong \mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_m$.

For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 2$ there exists a isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_{n^r} \cong \mathbb{Z}_n$.


I am interested in the prove of this Lemma.
If anyone knows the prove or a book where this Lemma is proven and please share it with me.


If the element $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$ is given by the numbers $x_k$, then those same numbers $x_k$ also define an element $x' \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and similarly an element $x'' \in \mathbb{Z}_m$. Try to show that the map $x \mapsto (x', x'')$ is an isomorphism. In verifying its surjectivity, the Chinese remainder theorem might come in handy.

If $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{n^r}$ is given by the numbers $x_k$, then the same numbers also define an element in $\mathbb{Z}_n$. This induces an isomorphism.


